# Can anyone decrypt this string using PHP?

Tags: php, encryption

Today I came across a job ad where you should decrypt a string that holds valid email address using PHP. So they posted this string, that represents crypted email address, and when you decrypt that email address you can send them email and show that you are Senior PHP developer.
And they posted another email address for Junior developers.

Now this seems to complicated for me so I wont send them email anyway since I already have a job, but I'm wondering is this even possible since you can't have key if using mcrypt functions.

Anyway, this is the string:
    MDA3MTY4MDAwODg4MDE0NzIwMDAwMzg4MDAwNDQ0MDAwNTEyMDAwMzg4MDI1NjAwMDA3NDg4MDA3Mjk2MDAzNTUyMDAyOTQ0MDAwODMyMDAzNjQ4IzYzNzIyMzI4NjY1NjM1

Company name is Aduro, and their emails are xxx@aduro.hr, so we are looking for email that ends with @aduro.hr

That string represents valid email address, is anyone good enough to decrypt this?

Comment: base64 decodes to `007168000888014720000388000444000512000388025600007488007296003552002944000832003648#63722328665635`.

Comment: It's not base64, this seems like MySQL encrypted

Comment: Contains too much repetition to be anything securely encoded for sure :)

Comment: @Jack It's something they want to be decoded. No need for secure encryption. Kinda like a CAPTCHA.

Comment: @Jack, yes, theres lots od "MDA", I tried explode this string with "MDA" and use those parts to decode with base64 etc, but it didnt work. This is really interesting, would love to se this decoded.

Comment: More like a sequence of 4 letters or 3 letters followed by a number. Probably has some meaning :)

Comment: @Jack, could be... hmmm... would reaaaaaly want to see this decoded, just wondering if its even possible, or they are just testing their custome algoritam against developers.

Comment: @otporan Could you post the link ? maybe there is a "secret" hint in the recruiting ad ?

Comment: My guess is their current "senior programmer" rolled his own "encryption" routine, and thinks its awesome. So he's suggested using this as a pre-interview test so they can filter applicants to get other people who think like he does. So I doubt that there's an easy standard one-line decryption possible on it; you'd need to run an algorithm similar to the one they've already got. But at the same time, although I haven't tried to decrypt this, I'd be willing to be that it wouldn't be too challenging for anyone with a bit of cryptography knowledge. Rule 1: Don't write your encryption routines.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV Its on Croatian so you wouldnt understand much. But its simple ad as simplest as it can get. Decode this string and contact us. Thats it nothing more trust me :D

Comment: Il give all of my reputation to anyone how decodes this as soon as I can!!!

Answer (score 6):

Not an answer, but some observations:

```
MDA3MTY4
MDAwODg4
MDE0NzIw
MDAwMzg4
MDAwNDQ0
MDAwNTEy
MDAwMzg4
MDI1NjAw
MDA3NDg4
MDA3Mjk2
MDAzNTUy
MDAyOTQ0
MDAwODMy
MDAzNjQ4
IzYzNzIy
MzI4NjY1
NjM1
```

Every column containing a digit only contains digits and lowercase letters.  Every column containing an upper case letter does not contain any digits.

If it is an e-mail address, then I would tentatively assign `IzYzNzIy` as the dot character '.'  Nothing immediately strikes me as likely to be the '@', possibly the `MDI1NjAw` because it is the only one starting with `MDI`.  The other non-`MDA`, `MDE0NzIw`, is in the correct position for a punctuation character in someone's name:  "Smith-Jones" say.  That would leave all the `MDA`s as alphabetic characters.  What is happening after the potential dot is anyone's guess.  Are there any single letter codes allowed there?  `NjM1` could be short for <CR><LF>.

Maybe we are looking at four character code elements?

```
MDA3
MTY4
MDAw
ODg4
MDE0
NzIw
etc.
```

Comment: Heeey good answer. Now, the company website is www.aduro.hr, so their email is probably xxx@aduro.hr This could help!

Answer (score 0):

Why are You thinking of `mcrypt`? It could be anything. Looks like a `base64_encode`d string.
Or something else. I think that they just don't want mails from 'senior' developers.

Comment: It's not a base64, it's more likely a AES_ENCRYPTED

Comment: @BrunoVieira It's unlikely to be something undecryptable like that.

Comment: @BrunoVieira How did You find out that?

Comment: I dont really know what is this, but I just cant decrypt it. I tried out of curiosity, but its something complicated really. Just wondering if anyone can decrypt this, or these guys are asking too much.

Comment: @BrunoVieira , aes needs password and they didnt provided any. So I dont think it can be aes. Nor md5, sha1 or any other hashing function since its one way only.

Comment: I thought of hash based solutions too, the only one that is not a hash and can be easily stored/retrived (as long as you have the key) are either ENCODE or AES_ENCRYPT, but in both cases a key is missing (and the format isn't the same by the way)

Comment: Could be multiple things. I.e. rot13+base64 or strrev+base64 or other

Comment: @BrunoVieira - do you even know what you're talking about?

Comment: Did you or your co-workers decrypted the String?

Comment: No, but that doesn't change the fact that you managed to amuse us with your inexperience, for which I have to thank you. Don't take this the wrong way, we all do mistakes, you can never associate an encrypted string with any kind of encoding and claim something resembles some SPECIFIC encryption algorithm.